# loading image vue src url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem to load image in vue.js

I tried to load my image but it does not work. If anyone have answer please teach me.

this is html source

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item" v-for="(obj, key) in portfolioJSON" :key="key">
          <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal2">
            <div class="portfolio-hover">
              <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img v-for="image in imageArray" :src="image" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </a>
          <div class="portfolio-caption">
            <h4>{{ obj.caption }}</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">{{ obj.title }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this is js code

```
export default {
  computed: {
    imageArray: function() {
        return this.portfolioJSON.map(obj => obj.img)
    }
},
    data: () => ({
        portfolioJSON: [
            {
                img: '/something/random/img.jpg',
                caption: 'test',
                title: 'test1'
            },
            {
                img: '/something/random/img.jpg',
                caption: 'Explore',
                title: 'test2'
            }
        ]

    })

}
```

It should load image and display it but it does not work.
Now it renders only one picture.

Comment: Chances are, the image not available at the relative path you have defined. Where is the image found? Is in the `public` folder, or some other static path? By using a relative path `../` you need to pay attention to the URL of the page that is requesting the resource.

Comment: Right, my images are in src/asset/image/portfolio/full01.jpg like this. I need to pay attention to the url as you say. Thanks @Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `portfolioJSON` variable is an array of objects. `src` accepts the path of a single image.

If you want to render all images in the array you should add this to your Vue instance:

```
computed: {
    imageArray: function() {
        return this.portfolioJSON.map(obj => obj.img)
    }
}
```

This code will generate an array of paths based on your `portfolioJSON` array.

Then, in your HTML, replace this:

```
<img :src="portfolioJSON" class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

with this:

```
<img v-for="image in imageArray" :src="image" class="img-fluid" alt=""></img>
```

That will render an `<img>` for every image in your `portfolioJSON` array (and you shouldn't forget to close your tags when using Vue, it might come back to bite you later).

Or you might want to use a single `<img>` element with `srcset` instead of `src`, in which case you should use this piece of HTML:

```
<img :srcset="imageArray.join(',')" class="img-fluid" alt=""></img>
```

Note that, in this case, you might want to provide other info in your `srcset` alongside the sources.

Comment: However I still cant render all images even tho i added cocmputed to vue instance. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Have you added the `v-for` in your `img` tag? Have you checked if all the tags are being added to the DOM?

Comment: Hi @Ayrton thank you for your asnwer. Yes I added v-for in `ìmg` tag and now I see that only one picture is rendered so there are 6 cards but same picture shows in all cards.

Comment: That's odd. Can you add your html template to your question?

Comment: yes, i just edited my code above. Could you please check? @Ayrton

Comment: I see. In your `img` tag, remove the `v-for` and replace this `:src="image"` with this `:src="obj.img"`

Comment: I made it @Ayrton, thanks a lot! Finally i could render all images!